# Что не так с getchar() или книгой Ритчи "Язык программирования Си"?

Tags: c++, c

Потянуло на изучение Си. Для "первого прыжка в воду" чтобы научится плавать, выбрал книгу Брайана Кернигана и Денниса Ритчи "Язык программирования Си". Во время изучения материала столкнулся с непонятным явлением подсчёта символов (п. 1.5.2 из книги). Итак, подробнее:

***(отрывок из книги)...** применим также инструкцию forвместо while, чтобы продемонстрировать другой способнаписания цикла.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* подсчет вводимых символов; 2-я версия */
main()
{    double nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}`
```

*Наконец, заметим, что если ввод не содержит ни одного символа, топри первом же обращении к getchar условие  в while или for не  будет  выполнено и  программа  выдаст  нуль,  что  и  будет  правильным результатом. Это важно. Одно из привлекательных свойств циклов while и for состоитв том, что условие проверяется до того, как выполняется тело цикла. Если ничего делать не надо, то ничего делаться и не будет, пусть даже тело цикла не выполнится ни разу.*

Судя по книге, при нажатии на Enter - программа должна выдать 0.
Что по итогам у меня - перенос строки и новый запрос на ввод от программы :))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ednFb.png)

На скриншоте выше - первые и последующие Enter`а - пустые, ввод никакой не осуществляется, помимо самого нажатия клавиши.

Что я делаю не так или чего я не понимаю?

Comment: Enter является полноценным символом и никогда не будет равен EOF, поэтому именно новый запрос на ввод и должен быть, всё правильно.

Comment: Попробуйте нажать `Ctrl + Z`, а потом `Enter`. И вы получите код, который будет интерпретироваться как `EOF`

Comment: Значит, в книге оппечатка? В тексте они явно указывают на "ввод не содержит ни одного символа"  :)

Comment: Ну он и не будет содержать ни одного символа. Опечатки нет, есть только ограничения консольного ввода, которые не позволяют в чистом виде прекратить ввод, нажав какую-то кнопку в углу экрана.

Comment: Книга ориентирована на работу в Unix, там нет проблем с передачей EOF в терминале. Впрочем, в винде тоже можно передать на вход программе пустой файл, как-то так, в cmd  -- `prog.exe < null`